# AppEngine: 404 error except home page on deploy server (works fine on local server)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to serve my first static website using google app engine. But it happens that I get 404 not found error except the home page on the deploying server. The strange thing is that everything is fine while running locally with dev_appserver.py, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /$
   static_files: index.html
   upload: index.html

- url: /(.*)/$
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: /(.*)/index.html

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css)$

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Here is some logs from command `gcloud app logs` when I try to access other pages by get request (more specifically here I'm trying url `mydomain/art/` which should be directed to `art/index.html` file in my project repertory):

```
2018-09-16 10:22:51 default[version]  "GET /art/ HTTP/1.1" 404
2018-09-16 10:22:51 default[version]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302
2018-09-16 10:22:51 default[version]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 204
```

whereas no problem on local server:

```
INFO     2018-09-16 10:23:12,434 module.py:880] default: "GET /art/ HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: You should show an example of the request you make and the GAE app log error that you see for it.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I've update some information in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/art/` request matches your second handler url.

The `upload` statement for it is not correct, instead of

```
upload: /(.*)/index.html
```

it should be (you have no parenthesis in the actual file path and it should be a path relative to your app/service directory):

```
upload: .*/index.html
```

The `/favicon.ico` request (which many browsers make by default) doesn't match any of your handlers `url` patterns. Your app appears to be intended to be visited by regular browsers so you may want to add a handler and a matching static file to cover it as well, otherwise such 404s are expected/normal.

The `/` request is matching the first handler `url`, the file is found (no 404), but I don't know why it returns a 204. Maybe something with the file content?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now!! (but I still don't understand why it worked locally)